# Dockerized flexdashboard app won't run in localhost

Tags: r, docker, shiny, flexdashboard

I am attempting to create a Dockerized Flexdashboard app. I am able to run it locally, but not in the localhost.
I can, however, run shiny apps just fine within the same docker image. Interestingly, the error message in the localhost says 'Not Found' for the Flexdashboard app which is different than when a page doesn't exist at all ('Page Not Found').

**How can I Dockerize a Flexdashboard app?**

## MWE

```
dir.create("testshinydocker")
dir.create("testshinydocker/apps")
dir.create("testshinydocker/apps/kmeans")
dir.create("testshinydocker/apps/kmeansflex")

cat(readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/master/050-kmeans-example/server.R"),
    file = "testshinydocker/apps/kmeans/server.R", sep = "\n")

cat(readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/master/050-kmeans-example/ui.R"),
    file = "testshinydocker/apps/kmeans/ui.R", sep = "\n")

cat(
  c('FROM rocker/shiny:latest\n',

  "RUN  echo 'install.packages(c(\"flexdashboard\"), \\",
  "repos='$MRAN', \\",
  "dependencies=TRUE)' > /tmp/packages.R \\",
  "  && Rscript /tmp/packages.R\n",

  'EXPOSE 3838\n',
  'COPY apps /srv/shiny-server/\n',
  'CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]\n'),
  file = "testshinydocker/Dockerfile",
  sep = "\n"
)

cat(readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/master/examples/11_shiny-kmeans-clustering/dashboard.Rmd"),
    file = "testshinydocker/apps/kmeansflex/kmeans2.Rmd", sep = "\n")

shiny::runApp('testshinydocker/apps/kmeans')

rmarkdown::run("testshinydocker/apps/kmeansflex/kmeans2.Rmd")
```

## Docker code (run in Powershell)

```
cd {path to testshinydocker directory}
docker build -t myapp .
docker run --rm -d -p 3838:3838 myapp
```

## localhost URLs

- http://localhost:3838/kmeans      (works)
- http://localhost:3838/kmeansflex  ('not found' error)
- http://localhost:3838/dinosaurs   ('Page not found' error)

**Shiny app works**
[image]

**Flexdashbord app 'Not Found'**
[image]

**Nonexistent dinosaurs page 'Page not Found'**
[image]

Comment: Hmm I ran your exact code and can see the `http://localhost:3838/kmeansflex` app.

Comment: Thanks @TylerRinker - I am really stumped by this. I suspect it's a settings issue on my personal machine and am hoping someone has experience with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a result of a bug in the rmarkdown package being used in your image (rmoarkdown v. 1.18) and is related to this: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1731 and https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1714.  I'm guessing http://localhost:3838/kmeansflex/kmeans2.Rmd does indeed work.

Here's how you could test this. Make a shiny app in the apps folder to see what version of rmarkdown is being run. Make a folder in **apps** called 'rmarkdown'. Then put the following simple ***ui.R*** and ***server.R*** scripts in there to build a shiny app (we know shiny apps render for you) to determine what version of rmarkdown you have:

### The ui.R script

```
fluidPage( 
  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))   
)
```

### The server.r script

```
function(input, output) {
​  output$value <- renderPrint({ utils::packageVersion('rmarkdown') })
}
```

Then `docker build` and re-`docker run` and go to http://localhost:3838/rmarkdown/ in the browser. It should take you to the screen and display the version of rmarkdown you have. If it is 1.18 that's the culprit.

[image]

### Potential Solution

If the **rmarkdown** installed is version 1.18 a possible solution would be to install rmarkdown from github in your Dockerfile so that you'd get a newer version without this bug and all is well.  Here's what that would look like in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

# apt-get and system utilities
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libssl-dev \
    libsodium-dev

RUN  echo 'install.packages(c("flexdashboard", "remotes", "openssl"), \
repos='$MRAN', \
dependencies=TRUE)' > /tmp/packages.R \
  && Rscript /tmp/packages.R

RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")' 

COPY apps /srv/shiny-server/


EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```